# Yii2 Как можно использовать app компоненты в консольном приложении?

Tags: yii2, консоль, компоненты

Файл **commands/FlagController.php**:

```
    namespace app\commands;

    use yii;
    use yii\console\Controller;
    use yii\base\Component;
    use app\components\flag\AbstractFlagService;
    use app\components\flag\FlagService;

    class FlagController extends Controller
    {
       public function actionCheck()
       {
            $flagService = \Yii::$app->get('flag-service');
            if(Yii::$app->flag->run()) {
                echo true;
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Конфиг **\config\console.php**:

```
     <?php use \yii\console\controllers\MigrateController;

     $config = [
       'id' => 'basic-console',
       'controllerNamespace' => 'app\commands',
       'components' => [
            'flag' => [
                'class' => 'app/components/flag/FlagService',
             ]
          ],
       ];

        if (YII_ENV_DEV) {

        $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
        $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        ];
         }
return $config;
```

Вылетает ошибка:

> Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class app/components/flag/FlagService does not exist'.

Как правильно использовать компоненты в консольных приложениях?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно указывать id класска, а не путь на диске. Лучше всего писать так:

'class' => app\components\flag\FlagService::class,